# Import vs C's #include

Tags: python, import

In C:

```
#include "foo.h"

int main()
{
}
```

I believe that "foo.h" effectively gets copied and pasted in at the spot of the "#include".

Python imports are different though, I'm finding.

I just refactored a bit of GAE code that initially had ALL request handlers in one big index.py file.

NEW directory tree:

```
+
|
+- [handlers]     // all inherit webapp.RequestHandler
+- [models]       // all inherit db.Model
|
+- globals.py     // contains global variables for site-wide settings
+- index.py       // contains all handler redirects
```

[**handlers**] is the folder with the handlers

[**models**] is the folder with the models

So, index.py goes

```
from globals import *  # we need all of the globals

# ...

from handlers.FirstPage import FirstPage
from handlers.SecondPage import SecondPage
#.. etc.
```

SHOULDN'T handlers.FirstPage and handlers.SecondPage **"see"** everything in globals, since globals is imported "first", before handlers.*?

Comment: Writing code that depends on C's behavior of `#include` basically copy&pasting your code into a file is bad practice even in C, and of course it doesn't work at all in Python because that's not what import does.  If declarations in FirstPage or SecondPage depend on globals, they should be importing globals themselves.  And if you were writing it in C, they should be #include'ing globals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While in C it works more or less "copy-pasting" the code, in Python is quite different.

Remember the Zen of Python?

```
Explicit is better than implicit.
...
Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!
```

Each time you import a module, you execute its code, but you keep all the scopes of the definitions. So, when you import `handlers` you give `index` access to the scope of `globals`, but the `handlers` module has no access to `globals` module unless you explicitly allow it to access to the scope, importing it.

Comment: _Each time you import a module, you execute its code..._.  Not strictly true.  The code is _executed_ only upon first import.

Answer (score 1):

yes, they're imported first, but they're imported first **into** `index.py`. To be "visible" `globals` need to be imported in respective files too.